# How to set multipart upload part size in Jclouds-2.0.x based S3 client?

Tags: amazon-s3, jclouds

Currently, I'm using "jclouds.mpu.parts.size" property to set mpu part size but with this jclouds 2.0.0 always uses default part size i.e. 32MB instead by provided part size.

How to set custom multipart upload parts size in Jclouds-2.0.x based S3 client?

Answer (score 0):

jclouds does not support configuring part sizes.  We track this issue at [JCLOUDS-1280](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-1280).